# Can you print a column using its index values instead of its name?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Extremely basic question. I am curious to know if this is possible (see question). I am aware that to print a column you just write `df["column_name"]`  and that´s it. But let´s say this "*column_name*" ist located at index 0, how would be the code to print this column using its index value?

I have tried  `df[0]` but doesn´t work. Just for clarity: I am not trying to find out the index value of a column, I have done that with `Index.get_loc` but to print its information using the index.

Or simply ist not possible to print DataFrame columns using its index values? Thank you very much for your time.

LG

Comment: Use `df.columns[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! Unfortunately the question had been already asked. But you helped me a lot. Thanks!